# Is there a shorter notation for identity function (fun x -> x) in F#?

Tags: syntax, f#

Is there a shorter notation for identity function (fun x -> x), other then defining your own? Writing

```
Seq.countBy (fun x -> x)
```

looks so wordy.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a short version `id` which is equal to `fun x -> x`

Also, for your case you can just do `Seq.sort`

Comment: Ooops, I meant `countBy` (edited the question). `id` is what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Not quite, I need counts of unique elements provided by `countBy`, `sum` does something else.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten what that function did